# typeError in calling user defined test library function ( with arguments ) in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have user defined function **saveLogin** in test library implemented as follows.

```
def saveLogin(userId,serialNo):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('new.db')
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES(?,?)",userId,serialNo)
    conn.commit()
```

When i try to call this function .
In test case sessionTest,

```
sessionTest
    saveLogin    ${CRE_USER_ID}    1
```

Getting following error :

```
sessionTest
          | FAIL |
**TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given).**
```

When i pass only 1 argument

```
sessionTest
    saveLogin    ${CRE_USER_ID}

sessionTest
   | FAIL |
**Keyword 'getSequence.Save Login' expected 2 arguments, got 1.**
```

Not able to figure out the reason for this error .

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the argument to the sqlite function execute .
execute function expects at most 2 arguments .
Modified function saveLogin to pass correct arguments to execute function.
Earlier i was passing 3 arguments , hence the error was coming.

```
def saveLogin(userId,serialNo):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('new.db')
    values = ( userId,serialNo)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES(?,?)",values)
    conn.commit()
```